# Form.Key disappears when form[].element is disabled

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms

When I disable

```
document.forms["Form1"].elements[okbn].disabled = true;
```

the corresponding entry in

```
this.Request.Form.AllKeys
```

disappears. How can I disable the button but keep the entry in AllKeys?

Answer (score 3):

`disable` means "Don't include this in the submitted data".

Perhaps you want `readonly` instead?

Comment: But `readonly` still leaves the button enabled. I want to suppres the further clicking...?